# Getting error in python code

Tags: python, eval

I am new learner in python

I have written a code in python..

```
#!/usr/bin/python
s = raw_input('--> ')
print eval('s+1')
```

I am getting error like this

```
  [root@python ~]# python 2.py
  --> 2
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 3, in <module>
  print eval('s+1')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

what could be the reason..

Comment: Don't use `eval`: [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: **Do not use `eval` for data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk that allows the user to run arbitrary code on your computer.**

Answer (score 1):

`s` will be a string, as returned by `raw_input`. Then you are trying to `eval` (which you should not do) `s + 1`. 1 is an integer, and as the error tells you, you cannot add a string to an integer.

If you intend for `s` to be an `int`, you can convert it.

```
s = int(raw_input('--> '))
```

But again, don't use `eval`.

```
s = int(raw_input('--> '))
print s + 1
```